# Creating incidents in Nagios

Tags: linux, scripting, nagios

I need to create an incident (using remedy, ICM, or third party tools) automatically whenever a `CRITICAL` alert pops up on Nagios tool. Can anybody recommend how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the nagios configuration where you define a `contact`, you have two options:

```
host_notification_commands
service_notification_commands
```

These ship with the default of `host-notify-by-email` and `service-notify-by-email` respectively, and those are defined with the `command` configuration option. You could define your own command, and put it next to one of the notify commands inside contacts, and It'll get run in addition to a page.

Alternatively, look for a plugin on the [Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/)

An example; IRC notifications plugin:

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Notifications/IRC/nagircbot/details

Answer (score 0):

Remedy can create incidents out of emails. Talk to your remedy admin, figure out the format the email needs to come in, and then modify the notification commands to send the email out as needed

Comment: Thanks all for the reply ,.!! that helps